# Illegal Instruction in Hello World Program

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, nasm, msys2

I have an Assembly file called "main.asm" which has the following code:

> ```
>     section .data
>     hello: db "Hello World", 10
>     helloLen: equ $-hello
> section .text
>     global _start
> _start:
>     mov rax, 1
>     mov rdi, 1
>     mov rsi, hello
>     mov rdx, helloLen
>     mov rdx, 14
>     syscall
>     mov rax, 60
>     mov rdi, 0
>     syscall
> ```

But when I assemble and link it with:

```
nasm -f elf64 main.asm -o main.o && ld main.o -o main && ./main
```

It gives me the following output:

[image]

This is weird because it worked for several days printing out "Hello World" and now it's this.

Comment: Works for me after copy/paste into `cat > foo.asm`, then assemble + link with `nasm` + `ld`, run on x86-64 Linux.  According to `strace ./main`, it writes `"Hello World\n\0\0"` to stdout because you hard-coded a length longer than `helloLen`, but there's nothing here that would fault on any x86-64.  So it's not a [mcve].  Use a debugger to see what instruction faults, e.g. see the GDB tips at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: Dunno. What is posted works just fine name `main.asm` with `nasm -f elf64 main.asm -o main.o && ld main.o -o main && ./main` Only other guess would be it was saved from a notepad file on windows in UTF-16 and `nasm` is choking on it. What does `file main.asm` show? Also, don't post an image of text for the error output, copy/paste and indent by 4-spaces so it formats in fix text, or include `\`\`\`none` on the line above the text and `\`\`\`` on the line below it to do the same thing.

Comment: Note that an assembler doesn't compile, it *assembles.*

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: UTF-16 would make it fail to *assemble*.  This builds ok but encounters an illegal instruction in the machine code when executed.  That could happen if the same machine code was executed in 32-bit mode.  (on an Intel CPU where `syscall` is only valid in 64-bit mode.)  But it wouldn't assemble that way with `nasm -felf32`; the (unnecessary) use of 64-bit register names would prevent it, so that could only happen with `objcopy` or some other way of getting 64-bit machine code executed in 32-bit mode.  Or like adding `bits 64` and then build with `nasm -felf32`

Comment: @fuz I've changed it.

Comment: Anyway, as fun as it might be to speculate about minor differences from what's shown in the question that could lead to this breakage, it's not a [mcve] and not answerable at all, and should be closed until it's edited with actual steps to produce the binary that fails this way, and with debugging details from GDB or another debugger.  Two separate people have verified that the example shown does work for them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my PC changed the Terminal from Kali Linux which I'm using with WSL to "Git Bash", it created a main.o and main file but it couldn't give an output from the file.

Comment: How does that explain the screenshot where it assembled and linked, but hit an illegal instruction at run-time?  In "git bash" (msys), I'd expect it to say something like exec format error, if the paths were even correct for `nasm` and `ld`.  Or are you saying NASM itself has a bug that makes it crash with an illegal instruction when trying to assemble this?  Seems highly unlikely; `nasm -felf64` can still make a `.o` regardless of what system it's running on.  (Even an ARM or MIPS cross-assembling for x86-64.)

Comment: Ok that makes more sense.  So perhaps in your "git bash" shell, `ld` can read an ELF object file, but still creates a valid PE32+ Windows executable?  And running that executable, the `syscall` instruction with those register values gets the Windows kernel to kill it in a way bash reports like SIGILL?  Or maybe it's a broken executable and something weirder happens when it's run.   I'm a bit curious now to see `file main` output on the executable that prints "Illegal Instruction" when you run it, and to know instruction actually faults if you run it under GDB.